# How can I draw a vertical line in an Activity when a button is pressed?

Tags: android, line, draw

I want to draw a straight vertical line in my Android activity when a button is pressed. Please explain how I can draw the line with a position & length I want.

**Elaboration:**
I have a linear layout with vertical orientation. A set of buttons constitute this linear layout. When I press one button, I want a line to appear to the right of these buttons, as if dividing the screen halfway - a straight line of width=2dip and height=200dip.

Comment: What kind of vertical line? What kind of activity? What kind of view? We need a lot more information

Comment: I've added an elaboration, hope this info is enough.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have solved it myself.
All you need to do is define a View with appropriate parameters and fill the background with color. You may want to use nested linear layouts for positioning the line correctly.

```
<View 
      android:id="@+id/View01"
      android:layout_width="2dip"
      android:layout_height="500dip"
      android:background="#2B497B"
/>
```

So if it may be useful to anyone else, I have posted the answer here myself!

Answer (score 3):

To draw dynamically u can use below code snippet:

```
 View view = new View(this);
 view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(2,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
 view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
 layout.add(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

The linear layout mentioned can be used as a divider by itself

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
        android:background="@color/black"      
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       />
```

I did this as my screen required a horizontal seperator dividing the screen into two halves..