# How to draw vertical line between two buttons in android

Tags: android

I have a simple linear layout. I am adding button dynaically through code one below other with some space in between. I need to draw a vertical line between those two buttons (Vertical arrow headed line in specific).

Could you please let me know how to draw a vertical line from buttom of button1 to top of button2.

I used DrawLine() to draw a line but its getting drawn below button2 with some offset.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class SampleMethodActivity extends Activity {
    Button b,b1;
    public int width,height,bottom;
     LinearLayout ll;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_method);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 12, 0, 40);

        b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("This is a sample text");

        b.setLayoutParams(params);
        b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ll.addView(b);


        b1 = new Button(this);
        b1.setText("This is a sample text to chck the width and height of a button1 and need to check how long it gets stretched and to check the width");
        b1.setLayoutParams(params);
        b1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ll.addView(b1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        width = b.getWidth();
        height = b.getHeight();
        bottom = b.getBottom();

        DrawView dv = new DrawView(this,width/2,bottom);
        ll.addView(dv);

     }
}
```

Below is DrawView class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int x,y;

    public DrawView(Context context,int x,int y) {
        super(context);
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        System.out.println("X: "+x);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y, x, y+400, paint);
    }

}
```

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809742/how-can-i-draw-a-vertical-line-in-an-activity-when-a-button-is-pressed

Answer (score 5):

**Drawing a Line with View**

If you only need a straight horizontal or vertical line, then the easiest way may be to just use a View in your xml layout file. You would do something like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Set first button `gravity to left` and other `to right` and in between them add a view in between them and set it's `gravity to center`.

**Second Way**

**Add button (weight 45) view(10) button2(weight45) and you are done.**
and you can also create an xml and inflate it to LinearLayout.

**For vertical line width to 1dp and for horizontal line height to 1dp**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to colors.xml

```
<color name="streat_line">#D0D5D8</color>
```

apply this where you want to create a line

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView"
android:layout_width="1dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/streat_line" >
```